# Angular: Updating a list; why is this $broadcast needed?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using a Service which contains a list and methods to manipulate that list. The Service is initialized in the `app.run()` and shared across multiple controllers.

`NavCtrl` contains a method for updating the entire list, while `FutureHomeCtrl` simply holds a reference to the list for use with ngRepeat (and other directives).

Since the actual list is contained by the Service and assigned by reference on `FutureHomeCtrl`'s `$scope`, I would have thought that any changes to the list would automatically be detected and digested by Angular. However I can only get the list to refresh if I manually re-set the reference to the Service's list using `$broadcast`.

Is my problem that I replace the entire list or something else? I should mention that I've also tried to `$apply()` with no luck - and again, I didn't think that should be necessary?

```
// Part of Service
MyHome.toggleAllLights = function (command) {
    var deffered = $q.defer();
    if (command && command === 'on') {
        // Works
        MyHome.Lights.turnOnAll().$promise.then(function (lights) {
            MyHome.lights = lights;
            $rootScope.$emit('MyHome.lightsUpdate');
            deffered.resolve();
        });
    } else {
        // Doesn't work
        MyHome.Lights.turnOffAll().$promise.then(function (lights) {
            MyHome.lights = lights;
            deffered.resolve();
        });
    }
    return deffered.promise;
};

.controller('NavCtrl', ['$scope', 'MyHome', function ($scope, MyHome) {
    $scope.toggleAllLights = function (command) {
        MyHome.toggleAllLights(command).then(function () {
            console.log(MyHome.lights);
        });
    };

}])

.controller('FutureHomeCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'MyHome', function ($rootScope, $scope, MyHome) {
    $scope.lights = MyHome.lights;

    $rootScope.$on('MyHome.lightsUpdate', function () {
        $scope.lights = MyHome.lights;
    });

}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is my problem that I replace the entire list or something else?

Yes, when you execute this code:

```
 $scope.lights = MyHome.lights;
```

The reference is copied to `$scope.lights`. Both reference to the same object in memory but the references (`$scope.lights` and `MyHome.lights`) are stored in separate memory blocks. Therefore when you replace `MyHome.lights` with another object, `MyHome.lights` references a new object, but `$scope.lights` **still references the original memory block**.

You could try:

```
$scope.MyHome = MyHome;
```

and modify your template bindings to add `MyHome` prefixes.

Comment: I see, as I suspected then. Looking beyond that hurdle, am I otherwise right in assuming that using $apply() is redundant?

Comment: @KG Christensen: this is not a problem with `$apply()`. The main problem is the original reference (`$scope.lights`) does not change.

Comment: Right, thanks. Also +1 for the suggestion about referencing the Service directly, should solve it.